# If element has specific CSS class and also ANY other class

Tags: html, css

I can't believe I've never had to do this before in my long time writing CSS but this has me stumped.

I have `span.item-name` and I want to add some specific styles only if this element has another class, which could be ANY class.

I've tried `span.item-name.*` and it doesn't do the trick. Is this possible and what are my options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the attribute selector. *(see: https://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Selectors#Attribute_Selector )*
example:

```css
body>.item-name:before, b {
  content:'Class name is: 'attr(class)'. ';
  color:purple
}
p[class*="item-name"][class*=" "]:before {
  color:green;
}
p[class^="item-name"][class*=" "]:before {
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<p class="item-name"> The basic class</p>
<p class="item-name another-class"> the basic class at first and then any other</p>
<p class="another-class item-name  any-more-class"> more than one class including <b>item-name</b> at any position</p>
```

Comment: This is PERFECT. Solves my current issue and definitely gives me some closure on how to accomplish this in the future. Thank you!

Comment: I haven't checked (I'm on mobile), but what about `<p class="item-name ">`?

Comment: @DavidThomas , p.item-name is just fine , the question was about 'select this class when among among other(s) ;)

Answer (score 2):

I think [this](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp) is what you want, scroll until you see the **CSS [attribute*="value"] Selector** section. For you it should be something like:

```
span[class*=" item-name"], span[class*="item-name "]
```

Why two selectors? Because `*=` search for that specific value, so only with the first selector `<span class="item-name another-class">` would not meet the criteria. That way you just search for the class, being unaware of its position in the `class` value.

Comment: Yup, this looks perfect. You would just have to avoid the typo of leaving a space (which can sometimes happen when adding classes dynamically) for your `.item-name`-only elements. Here's [a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jackkoppa/fq5yqaa6/2/) showing what would happen in that case (as expected, the space typo causes the extra selector to be applied)

Comment: Yeah, I know, but that is something that, unless JS is provided, is limited.

Comment: Absolute, totally agree.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe some more code will help, but you can't write functions for css, which it sounds like what you are asking for. You can simply just add another class if you need to.

`<span class="class1 class2">`